# "Unrecognized plugin: org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm2SMFormatter" error every time I run test in intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea

I am getting the following error every time I try to cucumber test using the cucumber plugin in Intellij Idea. I am using the following version deaIC-2017.3.5. I even tried installing the latest version - ideaIC-2018.2.4 - but the issue still persists. Anybody has any idea why this could be happening?

```
Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Unrecognized plugin: org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm2SMFormatter
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.addPluginName(RuntimeOptions.java:171)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.parse(RuntimeOptions.java:122)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:84)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:77)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:69)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:31)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

Comment: Do you have https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7212-cucumber-for-java plug-in installed and enabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the "Run/Debug Configuration", update "Program arguments" replacing --plugin org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm2SMFormatter by --plugin **org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvmSMFormatter**

Comment: Is there a way to fix this so that you don't have to update the Program arguments in each new run/debug configuration that gets created ?

Comment: @Joman68 you can modify the template for cucumber, so every time when you create a new cucumber configuration, it will use the template

Comment: @com2ghz if I modify the template to add `--plugin org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvmSMFormatter` to the Program Arguments then when a new run/debug configuration gets created it has the Program Arguments: `--plugin org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvmSMFormatter
--plugin org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm2SMFormatter`. Which still fails with an unrecognized plugin error. The `--plugin org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm2SMFormatter` is being added by the plugin to any existing Program Arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Let me illustrate how I encountered and found a way about to solve this problem.

I used to run my feature file by right clicking and run in intelliJ. Then I modified the program arguments in the edit configuration for that Run XYZ.feature file configuration.
In that process, I deleted the argument that passed " org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm4SMFormatter" and added "--thread 5" something like that.

And then when I was done with wanted to revert to the old config. It wouldn't run and throw this error. My hunch is that maybe the arguments are not being passed properly?.
Anyway the solution (kinda hack) is to choose another feature file ABC.feature and edit the configuration for Run ABC.feature and change the location path of the feature file to XYZ.feature and change nothing else. Maybe could rename the configuration to Run XYZ2.feature something like that.This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me: (intelliJ)
In the Program Arguments I have kept below line and it worked for me.

**--plugin org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvmSMFormatter** --monochrome --name "^Login with valid credentials$"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).